# PCCTS track input column number

Tags: lexical-analysis

How can I make PCCTS track the number of the tokens columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this may be one of the reasons that ANTLR was developed as an improvement over PCCTS:

http://sds.sourceforge.net/src/antlr/doc/lexer.html#trackingcolumn

However if you read the [PCCTS pdf book](http://www.polhode.com/pcctsbk2.pdf) you can see that there is an method for tracking columns.  Using the C api you can define the preprocessor symbol `ZZCOL`

Comment: But ANTLR uses Java, and I need C++. Could you elaborate more on ZZCOL?

Comment: If you read the PCCTS pdf that I linked to you can find the info about ZZCOL